# Extract rundeck executions from DB

Tags: oracle, rundeck

I would like to extract my executions of all projects in rundeck directly from DB, my rundeck is in a cluster and DB is in Oracle.

I've tried to do a Select from executions table, but was not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use Rundeck API wrapped on a bash script. Based on this:

https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/master/test/api/test-job-executions-status.sh

Check that:

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/#getting-executions-for-a-job

And here a lot of examples:

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest#096b9ef3-0017-931b-4991-235d014185c3

Comment: Tks for your reply, these are a very good material, but I need some more "readable". I'm new in JSON.